# What does MissingOrInvalidParts mean? Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am following this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-metadata/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k6P9.png

I am getting that error ^ and the size of my object is still 1kb when I try downloading it, so it never finalized.

Any suggestions? Better tutorials to follow for Model Derivative API?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show the full request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do have other tutorials like https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels
and also tools like https://oss-manager.autodesk.io
You can try those I believe.